# Zend Framework 2 including custom library

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My directory structure is like this:

- c:\Workspaces\Zend
- c:\Workspaces\Custom library

Custom library is a shared library, which is in use in other applications. It doesn't use namespaces, just old style underscores.

I downloaded the ZF2-Restful-Module-Skeleton which i intend to use as a restful server. In the InfoController I have this code:

```
namespace Main\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;

class InfoController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
  public function getList()
  {
    $data = array(
        'phone'   => '+30123456789',
        'email'   => 'email@domain',
    );

    $Res = new CL_Res_Chain_Mutable();

    return $data;
  }
}
```

Error message is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Main\Controller\CL_Res_Chain_Mutable' not found in C:\Workspaces\Zend\module\Main\src\Main\Controller\InfoController.php

Obviously, I need to add this custom library to my Zend application, but Im "little" lost here, I really don't know how to do this. I have googled couple solutions, but none of them seem to be like this.

Also, I have another library in folder `c:\Workspaces\Custom library 2`, which has (among other files) file(class) D.php, which I have used like D::dump($data);

How can I get it to work in my Zend application like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the `StandardAutoloader` to load your library classes. The easiest way is to modify the Application module's `Module::getAutoloaderConfig()` method so that it looks something like this:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
            'prefixes' => array(
                'CL' => 'c:\\Workspaces\\Custom library/CL',
                'D' => 'c:\\Workspaces\\Custom library 2/D',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

I've added a `prefixes` key and then listed the prefix name and where to find it on disk. The [Standard Autoloader documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html) has more details.

If you are working with a [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) you may also simply add these namespaces to your [init_autoloader.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php) file.

Comment: Thank you! I selected this as an accepted answer, but the note that I should add \ before class name was really helpful too! I was on the right track, but these really helped me to nail it right!

Answer (score 2):

The namespace of your class is `Main\Controller`. If you instanciate a new class here `new CL_Res_Chain_Mutable()` php will load it relative to the current namespace `Main\Controller\CL_Res_Chain_Mutable`. Your class is not a namespaced class so you need to load it from the root. Just put a \ in front `new \CL_Res_Chain_Mutable()`.

Answer (score 0):

By default your application will be using the Standard Autloader (PSR-0). This will find your files based on a namespaces, and a naming convension used by ZF2.
ZF2 will allow you to register multiple Autoloaders, so you can use different strategies, which is what you will need to do, here's an example:

Module.php

```
/**
 * Get autoloader config
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            // File containing class map key/value pairs
            __DIR__ . '/library/autoloader_classmap.php',
            // Or provide an array with the class map instead...
            array( 
                'Application\Bootstrap' => __DIR__ . '/application/Bootstrap.php',
                'CL_Res_Chain_Mutable'  => __DIR__ . '/library/pathhere/Mutable.php',
            ),
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

This setup will use tell ZF2 to check the class map first, if it can't find what it's looking for it will revert to the standard autoloader.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.class-map-autoloader.html