# Can anyone tell how to include custom libraries in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I have tried the way they used to include in Zend Framework 2 but it gives me an error

> Fatal error: Class 'Lib\FusionCharts' not found in /var/www/html/skeleton/module/Album/src/Controller/AlbumController.php on line 13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 including custom library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952697/zend-framework-2-including-custom-library)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. That links shows how to use the Zend\Loader which is deprecated. You need to register the lib with composer: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/migration/to-v3/application/#autoloading

Answer (score 0):

You must include path of your library before use :

```
/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';<relative directory path from this file>/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'fusioncharts.php';

$objFusionCharts = new FusionCharts();
```

Alternatively, if you use composer, you can add the path to your library `Lib` in the autoload-psr4 section of your `composer.json`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Lib\\": "relative/directory/path/from/your/baseDir"
    }
},
```

Then run :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Today autoloading classes using composer is industry standard, not an alternative approach. Alternative and old-fashioned way is using include/require statements.